# JMS that will work on app server that has lightweight client with out javaee requirement

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms

I am looking for a JMS that will run on Glassfish (or TomEE) and that authenticated users can use this service to get real-time-events. I want the users to be able to connect with an applet, a java web-start swing program, or eventually an android app. I'm not wanting a prerequisite for running a client to be that JavaEE must be installed on the users computer because the target user is the typical web user (probably not super computer savvy), and the JavaEE is a substantial install.

So my question is - is there a full featured JMS that can be run on the server side, while having a lightweight client side version (or a 3rd party jar) that just requires JavaSE or JavaME?

It seems that MQTT (JMS) and Eclipse Paho (lightweight 3rd party jar) may fit this bill, but are there any others?

Answer (score 0):

[ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) gives you a lot of client options, none of them requiring a giant footprint. In fact, with the HTTP and WebSocket based clients, you don't really need a Java client at all, but certainly well within the abilities of a JSE or JME client to interface with.

There's other JMS implementations with equally small client requirements so you can lower your sights, if you see what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Nicholas You can use ActiveMQ with REST , STOMP , Spring Websockets + STOMP + activemq